# How and why does "exec false" close the terminal?

Tags: command-line

I know that this is probably a relatively pointless question, but I am curious as to why `exec false` closes the terminal just like `exit` does.

I would also like to know if this is a acceptable way to close the terminal or not.

Comment: Also relevant reading: [What's the difference between eval and exec?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296838/85039)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`exec false` is replacing the current shell by the execution of the command `false` (here not the shell builtin but `/bin/false` or whatever `false` executable that comes first in the `PATH`) which quickly exits. If the shell was the topmost process running in your terminal emulator, there are no more processes running inside it so the terminal emulator is closed.

This is a an acceptable alternate way to close a terminal, just like would be many similar commands:

```
exec true
exec sleep 0
exec echo
...
```

See also: [what-does-an-exec-command-do](https://askubuntu.com/a/525788/18306)

Comment: As a side note, `bash` will perform certain cleanup before invoking `exec` including writing commands to `.bash_history`. So if one simply wants to save to `.bash_history` and launch a new shell in the same terminal window, one can do so by typing `exec bash`.

Comment: Ok thanks you answered my question perfectly :)

Comment: And a good question!  therefore upvoted both!  ;)

Comment: @jiliagre `exec` calls commands found in `PATH` , not built-ins.  For instance, `exec [[ $USER = root ]]` will return `bash: exec: [[: not found` error. In OP's case, `false` that is called is `/bin/false`, and not the shell built-in. Otherwise, good answer, hence +1. As a side note, `exec` can be sort of a  cut-off command, i.e. if those three commands in your example were made into a script, nothing beyond first `exec` would be reached, because `exec` would replace shell called by script with whatever command is on the right of `exec`.