# How can I view the stdout / stderr from the bash login shell?

Tags: bash, login, logging, stdout

I'm trying to debug a strange issue with my `~/.bash_profile`, and I'd like to be able to see if there are any errors / etc printed when it's run.  Is there some log or such somewhere that contains the stdout and/or stderr of the login shell process? Thanks!

The error only happens in the very first root login shell, not when re-executed or re-run in other contexts - it has something to do with that particular context / environment.  So standard tricks of tee / piping output / etc from an invoking terminal don't work.

Comment: If there are, usually they'd be printed in the terminal in which you ran that shell.

Comment: @muru I thought the same thing, I created a error in `~/.profile` without the existence of `~/.bash_profile` , the error message did not pass through. Check out my undeleted answer.

Comment: @stumblebee new terminal tabs won't run login shells unless you configure your terminal emulator that way

Comment: @muru You absolutely correct sir! ~./.bashrc does but ~/.profile does not. I should have run `sudo login`. Ill reduce to my original answer and suck up the shame.

Comment: You could source the file in your current terminal: `source .bash_profile`

Comment: Hi. Do you have any feedback on what was suggested? That is essential for the community.

Answer (score 0):

**stdout** and **stderr** will appear in the terminal everytime you do a login. You must log out and back in again for the changes in your profile to take effect.
A further explanation of the use of `~/.bash_profile` is provided
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510709/i-cannot-find-bash-profile-in-ubuntu) on Ask Ubuntu with a [good answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/510723/767056)

Answer (score 0):

Tbh I didn't try myself, but I'm pretty sure standard output and error are the terminal it's running on, as soon as the process starts. You can check by putting a command such as `echo "Hello world"` in your `.bash_profile`...

Answer (score 0):

To debug a bash script you have several options, and some of these are even more effective than redirecting stdout/stderr.

### Activate [trace](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html)

You could add to your `~/.bash_profile` (creating a trace only for specific parts of your script) with

```
set -x          # activate debugging from here
<commands>
set +x          # stop debugging from here
```

Also, `set -v` prints shell input lines as they are read, and `set +v` deactivates this.
With this alone you will likely catch the problem.

### Redirect trace

Use [Bash Variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) `BASH_XTRACEFD`

> If set to an integer corresponding to a valid file descriptor, Bash will write the trace output generated when ‘set -x’ is enabled to that file descriptor. This allows tracing output to be separated from diagnostic and error messages. The file descriptor is closed when BASH_XTRACEFD is unset or assigned a new value. Unsetting BASH_XTRACEFD or assigning it the empty string causes the trace output to be sent to the standard error. Note that setting BASH_XTRACEFD to 2 (the standard error file descriptor) and then unsetting it will result in the standard error being closed.

So you would use

```
exec 5> ~/bash_profile_ouput.txt
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"
<commands>
unset BASH_XTRACEFD
```

### Print line numbers

Use [Bash Variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) `LINENO` (and `BASH_LINENO`, `BASH_SOURCE` and/or `FUNCNAME` in more elaborate cases)

```
echo "Executing ${LINENO}"
<commands>
```

### Redirect stdout/stderr

Combine [command `exec`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525767/what-does-an-exec-command-do) with redirection, and possibly `tee`.
See answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131/redirect-copy-of-stdout-to-log-file-from-within-bash-script-itself), which also include other methods/"tricks" than using `exec`.

Related:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249890/pipe-bash-stdout-only-in-debug-mode
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334382/find-out-what-scripts-are-being-run-by-bash-on-startup
3. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script